# Sample .mp4 video file with 2 audio tracks download?

Tags: audio, mp4, channel

i want to try to experiment on jwplayer with video files which have 2 or more audio tracks. Can anyone provide me with a sample video or point to resource to download it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can find many examples available for download and freely licensed here:
https://cdn.media.ccc.de/congress/2019/h264-sd/
The filenames indicate which audio tracks are present, e.g. `eng-deu-fra` indicates English, German and French tracks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [MP4Box](http://gpac.io/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/) to construct such file as follows:

```
MP4Box -add file1.mp3 -add file2.mp3 output.mp4
```

You can use any format that MP4Box supports MP3, AAC, MP4, AVI, ...

I've created a simple example for GPAC's test files, available [here](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~concolat/html5_tests/count_audio.mp4).

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is what exactly I need! 

Much appreciated!

Comment: The link is broken: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable!